# Markup image with javascript and save

Tags: javascript, image-manipulation, frontend

I am trying to add markup to an image.  The user will be able to add text, drawings and images.  I am guessing it is easiest to do this with javascript on the front end.  My question is, what is the easiest way to save the final image.  Can the image be saved with javascript as well.  Do I need to serialize the image and save it on the back end?  Are there any good libraries that help with these kinds of problems, they seem pretty common.

I know this is open ended but any help on manipulating images with javascript and saving them to the the backend, java in this case, would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you looking for Java or Javascript? I have re-tagged so..

Comment: I am asking for both.  I want a way to save the changes made in javascript to java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the image in HTML5 canvas and draw on top of it using javascript.
When the user is finished you can use the toDataURL() method of the canvas to get a bit64 encoded version of the image which you can send or save as you like.
In your example you could send the 64bit encoded string to a webservice or api to save it.

consider this html

```
<canvas id="myCanvas">
</canvas>
```

then use this javascript to work with it:

```
//vanilla js, I advise to use a library like Kineticjs
//paint some things:
var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
//after the painting is done get the image
var bit64ImageString = can.toDataURL();
```

if you want to save the image on the server, use an Ajax call and send the bit64ImageString to the server. From that point on you can do whatever you want with it :)

Comment: I guess the squirrel example is the most similar to my question.  How do you take the input from javascript and save an image that can be saved by the server?

Comment: Both links are broken.